The orders of solvable Burnside groups
Let $B(d,n)$ be the rank $d$ free group of exponent $n$. Let $B(d,n,m)$ be the quotient of $B(d,n)$ by its $m$th derived subgroup, so that $B(d,n,1)$ is abelian (and finite).
It's easy to see that the "solvable Burnside groups" $B(d,n,m)$ are always finite. Is it "known" what their orders are? I'm particularly interested in the simplest nontrivial case: $B(2,n,2)$ (rank 2 metabelian group of exponent $n$).

If $n$ is a prime power, or in many other cases (e.g., $n$ is odd), for large $m$ (i.e. $m\ge m_0(d,n)$), $B(d,n,m)$ is the restricted Burnside group of rank $d$ and exponent $n$, so I don't expect its order be known. However, asking about the order of $B(d,n,2)$ (free metabelian groups of exponent $n$) sounds doable.

Is it only "easy to see" that these groups are finite using the restricted Burnside problem!? Or did I misunderstand the logic?

Is it obvious that they are finite even if you do use the RBP?

As far as I remember, even for the prime power case the lower bounds and the upper bounds are very far apart and I don't think anyone expect serious improvement.

@HJRW I was thinking that you’d just induct on the solvable length, using the fact that abelian burnside groups are finite.
